# Eclipse-Juno breakpoints not hit with PHP 5.4.8-1

Tags: php, breakpoints, eclipse-juno

Just installed Eclipse-Juno  and  the associated   PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK from org.eclipse.php.sdk.feature.group.

```
php --version yields:
    PHP 5.4.8-1~precise+1 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2012 14:58:46) 
    Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans

Php -m indicates that xdebug is loaded.
    [Zend Modules]
    Xdebug
```

In eclipse, Windows->Preferences->Php->Debug->PHP Debubber is Xdebug.

However, none of my breakpoints hit.

What should I check to make debug breakpoints work for PHP on Eclipse-Juno?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you are calling your scripts from a web browser. You need to tell xdebug to actually stop on breakpoints. If you are using Firefox, you can use [easyXdebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-xdebug/) for that. Make sure to enable remote debug in your xdebug.ini (explained in the extension preferences) and also in eclipse (Windows->Preferences->Php->Debug->PHP Debugger->Config). Then you can enable debug by clicking the little icon in your browser status bar for the next request.

For other browsers there should be Plugins as well, but I haven't used any.